# Perturbations around backgrounds with no symmetries

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, perturbation-theory

It is well-known that in perturbation theory around an FLRW spacetime, one can decompose any perturbation in terms of scalars, divergence-free vectors and a traceless symmetric tensor, known as the [scalar-vector-tensor decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar-vector-tensor_decomposition).

Moreover, for Schwarzschild-like backgrounds, with the same spherical symmetry, it is possible to decompose perturbations [similarly](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9301052).

The convenience is that the perturbation equations decouple. However, when dealing with a background with no obvious symmetry to exploit, is there still some convenient decomposition that can be applied or somehow derived which facilitates finding solutions?

Comment: So are you interested solely in perturbative solutions of EFE? There are some other examples for perturbation theory around GR background, for example for test scalar/spinor/etc. fields.

Comment: @A.V.S. I’m ultimately interested in methods to tackle/simplify the perturbation equations about a background without a large symmetry group. You can throw in extra fields I guess.

Answer (score 2):

For perturbation theory one always needs a nearby exactly solvable (completely integrable) theory; otherwise one cannot perform the computations. But completely integrable theories are always theories with large symmetry, though the symmetry need not always be manifest. This explains why one never sees perturbation theory done on concrete problems without symmetry.

Existence and stability statements for backgrounds without symmetry are based on general theorems for symmetric hyperbolic systems. These are proved using local inverse function theorems in infinite dimensions. In a very general sense (only), inverse function theorems are also perturbation theory, around the linearized equations at an approximate solution.

Comment: Then how do you determine the stability of a space-time which has no large symmetry to exploit? If it changes anything I should probably have added in my question I don’t expect to solve the problem abalytically - I fully expect numerics to be used.

Comment: @JamalS: One needs to invoke general theorems about the stability of symmetric hyperbolic systems. These are based on local inverse function theorems in infinite dimensions.